# The server tag is not well formed

Tags: c#, html

here'is my HTML :

```
<asp:Label ID="EmployeeIDlbl" runat="server" Text="<%# GetLabelCaption("Judges", "Employee Number",CaptionType.EditLabel) %>"></asp:Label>
```

where: `CaptionStyle` is `Enumerator` which i previously created , and `GetLabelCaption` function returns a string fetched from sql database.

I wanna know where is the error ?!!

Comment: You use databinding expression `<%#`, but you probably need simple echo `<%=`

Comment: @Tommi - you can't use `<%=` with server controls. You can use `<%#`. But why not use code-behind instead?

Comment: Indeed. Didn't see it's runat="server". __why not use code-behind instead__ - Some men just love declarative style. I can't agree with they, but it's their right.

Answer (score 2):

Put single quotes where you mention text as follows:

```
<asp:Label ID="EmployeeIDlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# GetLabelCaption("Judges", "Employee Number",CaptionType.EditLabel) %>'></asp:Label>
```

This will work

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the Text content in single quotes`(' ')` instead of double quotes`(" ")`. So try this

```
<asp:Label ID="EmployeeIDlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# GetLabelCaption("Judges", "Employee Number",CaptionType.EditLabel) %>'></asp:Label>
```